# I have 2 queries and i want to use result of first query in second one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries and i want to use result of first query in second one.
The first query is like:

> select id from category where like 'About Us'

Suppose this return **Cat_id = 2**

Now in my second query where i need to use the result of 1st query 
EG: i need to use the id(returned in query 1) to enter subcategory of About Us

The Second Query is like:

> INSERT into sub_cat VALUES(NULL,**2**,History) INTO(subCat_id, Cat_id,
>   'name')

so how can i use the value returned in 1st SQL query  into my 2nd Query

Comment: are you using a framework or SQL nav.....?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sub-query in your `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO sub_cat (subCat_id, Cat_id, `name`)
VALUES (NULL, (SELECT id FROM category WHERE name = 'About Us'), 'History');
```

This assumes that you do not have multiple categories with the same name. If your table *does* have categories with the same name, you can either add a `LIMIT 1` to the sub-query, or use a `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` statement like Stefan H. mentioned in his answer:

```
INSERT INTO sub_cat (subCat_id, Cat_id, `name`) (
    SELECT NULL, id, 'History' FROM category WHERE name = 'About Us'
)
```

Comment: This will throw error in the event that your subquery returns multiple rows.  An INSERT INTO SELECT would allow the OP to do multiple inserts

Comment: @StefanH It shouldn't, if you consider the idea that you can't have multiple categories with the same name. Also, the logic involved - adding a sub-category to an existing one - doesn't make sense to add the same sub-category to multiple parent categories; then, you'd have multiple parent categories with the same name that all have child-categories with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO SELECT is the query you want

```
INSERT into 
    sub_cat 
SELECT 
    NULL AS subCat_id,
    Cat_id,
    'name' as History
FROM
    Category
Where 
    YourColumn like 'About Us'
```